# Using Panelizer, how can I add a new menu item properly

Tags: 7, panels

I want to add a menu item *the right way* See "Edit IV Block" in the picture below.

[image: cog menu for panelizer]

That is the *wrong* way to do it.

The code is here: http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/panels/panels!plugins!display_renderers!panels_renderer_editor.class.php/function/panels_renderer_editor%3A%3Aget_pane_links/7.x

If you search for  drupal_alter('get_pane_links', $links, $pane, $content_type); you can see that the get_pane_links hook is supposed to fire, but for some reason it does not fire.

My question is, it seems like drupal_alter('get_pane_links') is the correct way to add menu items, but I've tried adding functions in other modules and they don't get called. I modified the code to do

```
echo 'before';
drupal_alter('get_pane_links', $links, $pane, $content_type);
echo 'after';
```

And no dice.
What is the correct way to add a menu item or how to I implement this hook?

Answer (score 0):

Cleared the cache and then it worked.
Found this by doing a $modules = module_implements('get_pane_links_alter');